# Uploading file, and insert the name of file to the database

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

It's me again. I have a problem in inserting the name of the uploaded file on the database. I've successfully uploaded the file and the file has been moved to the dir that I want, can anyone help me to figure it out what's wrong in my code? Also, I've tried putting some echo on it and I got "not success", and make the database value nullable. here's my code.

```
  <?php
        session_start();
        include "../../3rdparty/engine.php";
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        if ($_SESSION['daya_user'] != '') {

            if ($_FILES['dokumen']['name'] != "") {
                //print_r($_POST);
                    $path = $_FILES['dokumen']['name'];
                    $ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                    $nama_file = 'SO'.'-'.date("Ymd").'.'.$ext;
                    @copy($_FILES['dokumen']['tmp_name'], '../../dokumen_atk/'.$nama_file);

            mysqli_query($con,"insert into tbl_atk (name_file) values ('$nama_file')");
            header("location:../../index.php?mod=atk&submod=so_upload");
    }
}
//header("location:../../index.php?mod=atk&submod=so_upload");

?>
```

Comment: Where and when is `$_SESSION['daya_user']` set?

Comment: @Geshode when user login to the system.

Comment: Well, then we need the code for that, since it obviously is not set.

Comment: @Geshode all set, I tried the other form, and it's worked smoothly.

Comment: I just realized that the else belongs to the third if and not the first. Sorry, I got confused because of the indents.

Comment: @Geshode alright

Comment: @fauzio Have you checked the data type of field "name_file"? Is it set to varchar ?

Comment: @kittu yes, that field is varchar

Answer (score 0):

do it like this.

change this

```
$insert = $db->query("insert into tbl_atk_upload (name_file) values ('$nama_file')", 0
```

to

```
mysqli_query($con,"insert into tbl_atk (name_file) values ('$nama_file')");
header('location:success.php'); //redirect to your success page
```

> Note: you need to include your db connection and call it whenever when you use query. Like the given example variable `$con` above and don't enclose your query to **if/eslse** condition cause it's a bad habit.

Comment: include your database file something like this... include('conn.php');

Comment: I did, `include "../../3rdparty/engine.php";`